# Справочник описания культур C#

Tags: c#, строки, datetime, format

Имеется следующий код:

```
var date = new DateTime(2021, 9, 1);
result.MonthName = date.ToString("MMMM");
```

Данный код в зависимости от культуры извлекается разное написание месяца. Вопрос в следующем: где можно посмотреть какой-нибудь список, что вот при такой культуре извлекается так, а в при другой вот так?

Конкретно меня интересует культура, которая извлекает "Сентябрь" в данном случае (ru-RU культура извлекает "сентябрь" - с маленькой), но стало интересно, существует ли такой подобный справочник

Comment: [CultureInfo Класс](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?view=net-6.0#CultureNames)

Comment: Смотрите свойства класа [DateTimeFormatInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.monthgenitivenames?view=net-6.0)

Answer (score 3):

```
CultureInfo[] cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);
List<DateFormat> dateFormats = new List<DateFormat>(cultures.Length);
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;

foreach (CultureInfo culture in cultures)
{
    String[] dateTimePatterns = culture.DateTimeFormat.GetAllDateTimePatterns();
    DateFormat dateFormat = new DateFormat() { Culture = culture.Name , Date = new List<String>(dateTimePatterns.Length) };
    foreach (String dateTimePattern in dateTimePatterns)
    {
        dateFormat.Date.Add($"{dateTimePattern}  -  {date.ToString(dateTimePattern , culture)}");
    }
    dateFormats.Add(dateFormat);
}
public class DateFormat
{
    public String Culture { get; init; }
    public List<String> Date { get; init; }
}
```

Берём все известные культуры и смотрим на формат их дат

Comment: Спасибо! То, что нужно прям!